# Client username/windowsIdentity from web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

How can I fetch client's WindowsIdentity from web service without impersonating?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of impersonation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Web and use below code:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: its null always, any suggestions?

Comment: Set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to true: <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation lets a service call something else while acting as the user who called the service. To just get the identity of the user calling the service, you don't need impersonation (but you do need authentication enabled).

Comment: When is impersonation required? isnt it better for auditing purposes?

Comment: Impersonation is only required if the service needs to do something with the user account of the user who called the service. Say if the service needs to read c:\asdf.txt and needs to do it as Bob (who called the service). Normally you don't need impersonation as the service has the necessary permissions.  (One case where you might need it is when a service calls another service as the user who called the first service, but that gets VERY complicated.)